# How do I to send custom HTTP error responses in String?

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller

I am stuck with validating a String if the url is sending the path variables with invalid data.

Currently, the exception is throwing back a response. But I want to send back the response with a message.

E.g `{"message": "Invalid Data"}`.

I'm using @RestController API.

`URL: ==> http://((domain))/getdata/"dd"`

```java
@GetMapping(value = { "/{id[]}" })
public ResponseEntity<JsonNode> getData( @PathVariable(name = "id[]") Long[] id ) {..}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your question more precisely? If you are interested in error handling with spring please have a look at [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring)

Comment: If the specified path does not exist, the server should respond with HTTP status code 404

Comment: besides from that: why do you define the path variable as an array of longs and then pass chars in the URI to it?

Comment: thanks for the reply Melkor.
Its actually added for validation purpose.

Comment: Well, this does not answer my questions. If you are still interested in solving your issue please explain what you want to achieve exactly and what prevents you from doing so. I neither understand your question nor your problem.